# Create an if statement in for a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case

I want to have a view that looks like the following same sample where the data is pulled from 3 different tables

[image: sample resultant table]

I want to create a query that will select each of the `company` with their `location`, `rooms` and `adddress`, but if the `company` has a location in `CA` I don't want to select any of the other ones in either `NY` or `OR`. I seen `CASE` but I am not certain how to use it in this case since I don't want to enter the name. Right now my query is something like this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT
     DBO.HOTEL.COMPANY, DBO.HOTEL.LOCATION AS LOCATION, DBO.AMOUNT.ROOMS, 
     DBO.PERSON.OWNERS, DBO.PERSON.ADDRESS
 FROM DBO.HOTEL INNER JOIN DBO.HOTEL.ID = DBO.AMOUNT.HOTEL_ID INNER JOIN
      DBO.HOTEL.ID = DBO.PERSON.HOTEL_ID
 WHERE (LOCATION = 'OR' OR LOCATION = 'CA' OR LOCATION = 'NY') AND
       DBO.HOTEL.OPEN_DATE >= 01/01/2015
```

Comment: if one of the answers helped you, could you please mark it as accepted to give closure to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS on this context:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT
  DBO.HOTEL.COMPANY,
  DBO.HOTEL.LOCATION AS LOCATION,
  DBO.AMOUNT.ROOMS, 
  DBO.PERSON.OWNERS,
  DBO.PERSON.ADDRESS
FROM
  DBO.HOTEL INNER JOIN DBO.HOTEL.ID = DBO.AMOUNT.HOTEL_ID
  INNER JOIN DBO.HOTEL.ID = DBO.PERSON.HOTEL_ID
WHERE
  LOCATION = 'CA' OR (
    (LOCATION = 'OR' OR LOCATION = 'NY')
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM DBO.HOTEL h
        WHERE h.id=DBO.HOTEL.ID AND LOCATION='CA'
      )
    )
  AND DBO.HOTEL.OPEN_DATE >= '01/01/2015'
```

Comment: I get the following error `Invalid column name 'id'.` for the  `WHERE h.id=DBO.HOTEL.ID AND LOCATION='CA'` line

Comment: @Tavo is your db case sensitive? Can you try with h.ID ?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you want to select each of the company with their location, rooms and address. If a company is in CA, you just want that listed.

You could try something like this (Example here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9897/1):

```
create table hotel (
    company char(2),
    location char(2),
    rooms int,
    owners char(3),
    address varchar(20)
);

insert into hotel values 
('C1', 'NY', 32, 'BAP', '123 Appl'),
('C1', 'CA', 21, 'BAP', '123 Appl'),
('C1', 'OR', 24, 'BAP', '123 Appl'),
('C2', 'OR', 54, 'RED', '123 Appl'),
('C3', 'CA', 35, 'EDR', '123 Appl'),
('C4', 'NY', 14, 'LPD', '123 Appl'),
('C5', 'NY', 48, 'LPD', '123 Appl'),
('C6', 'CA', 98, 'WES', '123 Appl'),
('C6', 'OR', 56, 'WES', '123 Appl'),
('C7', 'OR', 61, 'YTR', '123 Appl'),
('C8', 'OR', 12, 'YTR', '123 Appl'),
('C9', 'CA', 25, 'MAD', '123 Appl'),
('C9', 'NY', 65, 'MAD', '123 Appl'),
('C9', 'OR', 38, 'MAD', '123 Appl');

select * from hotel
where location = 'CA'
    union all
select * from hotel
where company not in (select company from hotel where location = 'CA');

Result
company location    rooms   owners  address
C1      CA          21      BAP     123 Appl
C2      OR          54      RED     123 Appl
C3      CA          35      EDR     123 Appl
C4      NY          14      LPD     123 Appl
C5      NY          48      LPD     123 Appl
C6      CA          98      WES     123 Appl
C7      OR          61      YTR     123 Appl
C8      OR          12      YTR     123 Appl
C9      CA          25      MAD     123 Appl
```